# Postgres CSV import - handle empty strings as integers

Tags: postgresql

I have a ton of CSV files that I'm trying to import into Postgres. The CSV data is all quoted regardless of what the data type is. Here's an example:

`"3971","14","34419","","","","","6/25/2010 9:07:02 PM","70.21.238.46   "`

The first 4 columns are supposed to be integers. Postgres handles the cast from the string `"3971"` to the integer `3971` correctly, but it pukes at the empty string in the 4th column.

`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""`

This is the command I'm using:

`copy "mytable" from '/path/to/file.csv' with delimiter ',' NULL as '' csv header`

Is there a proper way to tell Postgres to treat empty strings as null?

Comment: CSV data is always going to be strings as it is a text format. The presence of quotes is determined by the program settings for outputting the data. As to your issue look at `FORCE_NULL` here [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). Or have the program that is outputting the data not quote everything so you end up with: `3971,14,34419,,, ...`

Comment: Fair enough. I should have said that the data is all quoted. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this. Since I'm working in `psql` and using a file that the server user can't reach I use `\copy`, but the principle is the same:

```
create table csv_test(col1 integer, col2 integer);

cat csv_test.csv 
"1",""
"","2"

\copy csv_test from '/home/aklaver/csv_test.csv' with (format 'csv', force_null (col1, col2));
COPY 2

select * from csv_test ;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 | NULL
 NULL |    2
```

Comment: From your example, I have to know ahead of time which columns will need this, right?

Comment: Or you could include all the columns, in which case all `''` will be turned to `NULL`. It just depends on whether you are depending on `char` columns to have `''` values or not. I know there are systems that count on `'' IS NULL`.